# PHP - How is don't sign off checkbox realized?

Tags: php, http, session, session-cookies

i want to have checkbox at login screen and when user check that checkbox and log in, he stay logged all the time. But in php in php.ini is session.gc_lifetime directive and it is for whole session.save_path directory, so if for example sessoion.gc_lifetime is set for 1440 seconds, user check that checkbox, log in, turn off computer for 2 hours, then turn on computer and get to my site, he will be log off, cause php garbage collector knows about last access time of that session file and cause (last access time + session.gc_maxlifetime ) < time, gc delete that session file. Sry for my bad english.

Comment: Set a time limit for some unreasonably long time in the future? (ie 30 days)

Comment: You mean session.gc_lifetime? But that will be for whole session.save_path directory, so all users will have that settings.

Comment: Usually, a _sepearate_ cookie is saved which only identifies a user which a longer lifetime, so sessions can be cleared without a problem, and you just log in (and create a new session), based on that cookie. The value of the cookie is most often stored in a database, connecting it with a user-id.

Comment: I meant with a cookie, sorry. wasn't clear.

Comment: What is the value of session.cookie_lifetime? The default (0) will destroy cookies when the browser closes.. The session might still live on, but the cookie that links your browser to the session you had might be getting destroyed.

Comment: ghbarratt - yes, but that problem is not cookie in browser, but session file on the server, because php gc destroy it when session.gc_maxlifetime elapsed.

Comment: wrikken: cookie can be modified in browser np, so i dont know if this is good idea, because someone can copy that cookie

Answer (score 1):

Sessions were more designed to temporary...when the browser closes or a short time period has passed.  If you want to have the user stay logged in forever you should use [setcookie](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) with a long expire paramater.

```
setcookie( "TestCookie", $value, time()+3600*24*365 ); //3600*24*365 = 1 year
```

This cookie will exist for a year